# Flink session window not working as expected

Tags: flink-streaming

The session window in Flink is not working as expected on **prod env** (same logic works on local env). The idea is to emit the count of 'sample_event_two' for a specific **user Id** & **record id** incase if there is at least one event of type 'sample_event_one' for the same **user Id** & **record id**. **ProcessingTimeSessionWindows** with session gap of 30 mins is used here and **ProcessWindowFunction** has the below logic (I am doing a keyby **user Id** and **record Id** fields before setting the window size),

```
  public void process(
      String s,
      Context context,
      Iterable<SampleEvent> sampleEvents,
      Collector<EnrichedSampleEvent> collector)
      throws Exception {

    EnrichedSampleEvent event = null;
    boolean isSampleEventOnePresent = false;
    int count = 0;


    for (SampleEvent sampleEvent : sampleEvents) {

      if (sampleEvent.getEventName().equals("sample_event_one_name")) {

        Logger.info("Received sample_event_one for userId: {}");
        isSampleEventOnePresent = true;

      } else {
        // Calculate the count for sample_event_two
        count++;

        if (Objects.isNull(event)) {
          event = new EnrichedSampleEvent();
          event.setUserId(sampleEvent.getUserId());
        }
      }
    }

    if (isSampleEventOnePresent && Objects.nonNull(event)) {
      Logger.info(
          "Created EnrichedSampleEvent for userId: {} with count: {}",
          event.getUserId(),
          event.getCount());
      collector.collect(event);
    } else if (Objects.nonNull(event)) {
      Logger.info(
          "No sampleOneEvent event found sampleTwoEvent with userId: {}, count: {}",
          event.getUserId(),
          count);
    }
  }
```

Though there is sample_event_one present in the collection (confirmed by verifying if the log message "Received sample_event_one" was present) and the count is calculated correctly, I don't see any output event getting created. Instead of EnrichedSampleEvent being emitted, I see log message "No sampleOneEvent event found sampleTwoEvent with userID: "123, count: 5".  Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProcessWindowFunction` will be called for each key individually. Since the key is a combination of user id and record id, it's not enough to know that "Received sample_event_one" appears in the logs for the same user. Even though it was the same user, it might have had a different record id.